# ReferenceError: data is not defined in nodemailer.sendMail()

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am using Node.js v18.15.0 and nodemailer to send an email in my E-commerce application. However, I am getting a "ReferenceError: data is not defined" error in my emailCtrl.js file. Specifically, the error occurs in the sendMail() function, where I am trying to set the recipient email address using the "to" field.

Here is the relevant code in my emailCtrl.js file:

```
// send mail with defined transport object
let info = await transporter.sendMail({
  from: '"hey" <abc@gmail.com>',
  to: data.to, // Error occurs here
  subject: data.subject,
  text: data.text,
  html: data.html,
 });

// Generate Password Token
const forgotPasswordToken = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;
  const user = await User.findOne({ email });
  if (!user) throw new Error("User not found with this Email");
  try {
    const token = await user.createPasswordResetToken();
    await user.save();
    const resetURL = `Hi Please follow this link to reset your 
Password. This link is valid for 10 minutes from now. <a 
href="http://localhost:5000/api/user/reset- 
password/${token}">Click Here</a>`;

    const data = {
      to: email,
      subject: "Reset Password Link",
      text: "Hey user",
      html: resetURL, // fixed the typo here
    };
    console.log(data);
    sendEmail(data);
    res.json(token);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
});
```

I have tried to fix the error by making sure the "data" object is defined, but I am still getting the error.

Can someone please help me figure out what's causing this error and how to fix it?

Relevant info about environment:

Node.js v18.15.0
nodemailer

Comment: Are you sure that data is defined correctly? Maybe its defined but it doesnt have `to` property defined, try adding a console log or debugger to check `data` object

Comment: Maybe a scope problem ? Could be useful to see your code a little more, where do you define that `data` object?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I added a console log to check the data object and it displayed all the necessary details. However, it appears that the email functionality is not working properly and emails are not being sent as expected. Do you have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot it further?

Comment: const nodemailer = require("nodemailer")
 const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler")
 const sendEmail = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
   let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     host: "smtp.gmail.com",
     port: 587,
     secure: false, 
     auth: {
       user: process.env.MAIL_ID,
       pass: process.env.MP, 
     },
   })
   let info = await transporter.sendMail({
     from: '"hey" <abc@gmail.com>', 
     to: data.to, // fixed the error here
     subject: data.subject, 
     text: data.text,
     html: data.html,
   })
 })

Comment: Yes I understand that `data` is defined somewhere but it would be useful to see where it is in your code, maybe it's unreachable in the scope of the `sendMail` argument.

Comment: @Peterrabbit can you check the code

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be some mixup with scopes, you defined `data` in the scope of the closure inside `asyncHandler` but the `data` object you are trying to use in the argument of `let info = await transporter.sendMail` is indeed undefined.

```js
// The reachable scope for the object passed as argument in sendEmail is here, 
// So this would be the right place to define it :
/*
const data = {
  to: "...",
  subject: "...",
  text: "...",
  html: "..."
};

// and then
let info = await transporter.sendMail({
  from: '...',
  ...data, // (use the rest operator to copy the fields of the object and you won't have to copy manually each one of them)
});
*/

let info = await transporter.sendMail({
  from: '"hey" <abc@gmail.com>',
  to: data.to, // This data is not defined in that scope in your code
  subject: data.subject,
  text: data.text,
  html: data.html,
});

const forgotPasswordToken = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  // ...
  // The object data defined here is only reachable in the scope of that closure
  const data = {
    to: email,
    subject: "Reset Password Link",
    text: "Hey user",
    html: resetURL,
  };

  sendEmail(data);
  // ...
  // and it goes out of scope here
});
```